# Trying to convert old mysql db on ARCHIVE engine to innodb

Tags: mysql, storage, innodb, archive

I have a very old db that apparently is built using an engine called Archive Storage Engine - which apparently isn't supported out of the box with newer versions of MySQL - apparently there's a switch you add when you compile that builds it in....

Anywho - I'm trying to somehow recover this data either by: 
1) Converting all the tables' engines to innodb - with a version of mysql that has archive and innodb supported in it?
OR
2) somehow find a functioning mysql version that still supports it, so I can somehow dump the tables and alter the sql file to implement innodb on import?

Are either of these possible? Any guidance or pointing in the right direction would be supremely helpful. I don't know much about these engines to begin with, and even less about Archive. I may even be asking the impossible?

Thanks everyone in advance!

EDIT: I was able to download an older version of mysql that supported all the engines. Was able to load all the database files and the ib* files (which I read in another post is necessary) from the root mysql dir, and I was able to dump each table out as a separate file. I then replaced all ENGINE=ARCHIVE with ENGINE=InnoDB and was able to import those tables back into the server mysql and all worked.

Comment: Are you trying to restore a file backup or something generated from mysqldump

Comment: This was a functioning DB and then it went "corrupt" and screwed up mysql. I had to move it out of ../mysql/data. I used a recent backup and extracted the DB dir from the snapshot and was able to see the db and tables in mysql (which i'm running locally on win10). When i try a 'select * from [table];' MOST of tables result in a 'table doesn't exist' error, SOME will show me all the rows and columns. My suspicion is that the version of mysql I d/l doesn't support ARCHIVE & some tables are using myisam, prob why i can see data. Would love to mysqldump everything if i can access all the data

Comment: There can be many reasons for corruption. Archive is not the easiest to recover. I suggest paying a MySQL professional if the data is important. Either way backups are important make sure you take them in future

Answer (score 0):

The changelogs imply that the ARCHIVE Engine has not been removed from either MySQL or MariaDB.

What version are you running.

Can you `SELECT` from the Archive table?  If so then this should work:

```
CREATE TABLE new ( ... ) ENGINE=InnoDB
    SELECT * FROM my_archive_table;
```

What files exist in the directory with the name of the database?  There should be a `my_archive_table.frm` file and at least one other.

What does this give you:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'my_archive_table';
```